# Hows My UML activity Diagram design just checking to make sure

Tags: android-activity, uml, diagram

Wondering if I did it correctly on especially after standard petrol and premium petrol I think both should go into a merge node then lead into add fuel as for the diesel one am not sure if it's correct any advice is appreciated if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The Actions on your Activity diagram should be what their name suggest: Descriptions of action performed by the subject.

The Actions `Petrol`, `Diesel`, `Premium Petrol` and `Standard Petrol` do not fit that definition and should be removed.

Going from `Diesel` to the mergenode, or directly to `Add Fuel..` is in this case the same. That could change if you needed some kind of gard condition on the flows that came from the Petrol choice, that didn't play for the Diesel choice.